# Reading JSON with jQuery and matching fields by their ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently getting a JSON with two objects: One is COLUMNS while the other is DATA. Each of those are arrays with the appropriate column names and matching data, respectively.

Here is the JSON:

```
{  
   "COLUMNS":[  
      "NUM",
      "USERID",
      "NAME",
      "YEARCREATED",
      "LASTCONTACTED",
      "RELATIONSHIP"
   ],
   "DATA":[  
      [  
         8,
         333,
         "Joe Smith",
         2015,
         "January, 19 2015 00:00:00",
         "30 Days"
      ]
   ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate over the DATA array (currently there's only one object in the array) using jQuery:

```
var jsonSource = {"COLUMNS":["NUM","USERID","NAME","YEARCREATED","LASTCONTACTED","RELATIONSHIP"],"DATA":[[8,333,"Joe Smith",2015,"January, 19 2015 00:00:00","30 Days"]]} 

    $.each(jsonSource, function( COLUMNS, DATA ) {
       console.log( jsonSource );
    });
```

What I'm getting back in my console is the entire JSON tree.

How do I get the output to be "Joe Smith" (without quotes)?

Comment: you can use `jsonSource.COLUMNS` to get COLUMNS's value and `jsonSource.DATA` to get DATA's value

Comment: What do you mean by How do I specifically ask for DATA.val for COLUMNS.NAME? What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: The output I'm expecting is "Joe Smith" (without the quotes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATA` is the array of columns with the actual data so for now just ignore `COLUMNS`.

```
$.each(jsonSource.DATA, function( COLUMNS, DATA ) {
    console.log( jsonSource );
});
```

Now looking at [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) documentation you can see the callback method gets `indexInArray` and `value` as parameters so lets update the callback. Keep in mind that indexInArray is related to how many rows exist in DATA, not the position of `NAME`, etc in `COLUMNS`.

```
$.each(jsonSource.DATA, function( indexInArray, value ) {
    console.log( jsonSource );
});
```

Now instead of outputting the entire JSON tree, lets use the specific iteration of each. And since we know that `NAME` is the third item in the row we'll just hardcode that for now.

```
$.each(jsonSource.DATA, function( indexInArray, value ) {
    console.log( value[2] );
});
```

Now lets say that the ordering of `COLUMNS` isn't guaranteed. We always want `NAME` but it could be any column.

```
$.each(jsonSource.DATA, function( indexInArray, value ) {
    console.log( value[jsonSource.COLUMNS.indexOf('NAME')] );
});
```

Of course that's a complex line so in a real program you would probably want something like this.

```
function getColumnIndex(columns, key) {
    return columns.indexOf(key)
}

var nameIndex = getColumnIndex(jsonSource.COLUMNS, 'NAME');

$.each(jsonSource.DATA, function( indexInArray, value ) {
    console.log( value[nameIndex] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this

```
for (var dataIndex in jsonSource.DATA) {
    for (var index in jsonSource.COLUMNS) {
        console.log(jsonSource.COLUMNS[index], jsonSource.DATA[dataIndex][index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonSource = [{"COLUMNS":["NUM","USERID","NAME","YEARCREATED","LASTCONTACTED","RELATIONSHIP"],"DATA":[[333,"Joe Smith",2015,"January, 19 2015 00:00:00","30 Days"]]}]

$.each(jsonSource, function( i, item ) {
   console.log( i.COLUMNS );
   console.log( i.DATA );
});
```

Comment: Care to elaborate ? Code-only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have an inconsistency on the two objects. Maybe it should be this?

```
var json = {  
  "COLUMNS":[
     "NUM",
     "USERID",
     "NAME",
     "YEARCREATED",
     "LASTCONTACTED",
     "RELATIONSHIP"
  ],
  "DATA":[[
      8,
     333,
     "Joe Smith",
     2015,
     "January, 19 2015 00:00:00",
     "30 Days"
  ]]
}
```

Then you can iterate like this:

```
var cols=json['COLUMNS'];
var data=json['DATA'];
for (var key in data) {
  var numVal = data[key][0];
  var uid = data[key][1];
  var name = data[key][2];
  var year = data[key][3];
  var last = data[key][4];
  var rel = data[key][5]
}
```

Comment: I think DATA is supposed to be an array of arrays because it's simulating multiple rows.